# mongoose Document doesn't map a property correctly

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have a nodeJS Server with express project with a mongoDB.

I want to map this object, coming from an endpoint:

```js
{ 
     userId: '5ca14305e73fc8453843d3e1',
     bookingId: '29b0c5e0-e504-43bc-b5a1-9326d7d41d45'
}
```

Its defined through a class like this:

```
export class CreateBookerDto {
     @IsString() readonly userId: string;
     @IsString() readonly bookingId: string;
}
```

This is my actual code doing the mapping:

```
export interface IBooker extends Document {
    userId: string;
    bookingId: string;
    createdAt?: number;
}

constructor(
     @InjectModel('Booker') private readonly bookerModel: Model<IBooker>
) { }

async createBooker(booker: CreateBookerDto) {
     let createdBooker = new this.bookerModel(booker);
     createdBooker.createdAt = moment.now();
     return createdBooker.save();
}
```

This is my output from createdBooker before the save:

```
{
     _id: 5ca146e4ba2c08380c435453,
     bookingId: '29b0c5e0-e504-43bc-b5a1-9326d7d41d45' 
}
```

Where and why does he drop the properties userId and createdAt?

Comment: Ok, i wrapped the userId and bookingId in another object and it seems fine now.